# I am trying to make a buttons forecolor change when clicked and when it is clicked again it will revert back to its original color

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a buttons forecolor change when clicked and when it is clicked again it will revert back to its original color and it loops that. Basically like a toggle that changes the color of a button when clicked and when clicked again reverts it to its original color. I am doing this in c# and I have searched Multiple forums for an answer to this and no one has this specific problem so I am asking if you can please help me with the code. I have no code now because I do not know what to start with and ive tried multiple different things that havent worked.

I have tried to have the buttons forecolor change when clicked which is easy but then reverting it back is hard and then looping it is something i cant seem to get working right now. None of my code works so I just request if it is possible a kind forum member can assist me with my code or provide me with code i need. Thank You.

Comment: You know the color you're changing the button to, right? And the color it started as?

Comment: Why not just check the button's color, and if it's Color1 change it to Color2, and if it's Color2 change it back to Color1?

Comment: What do you mean by "it loops that"? Do you mean that it goes back and forth between colors as you click the button repeatedly, or do you mean that it changes back and forth by itself once someone clicks?

Comment: BTW, you really should show us SOME code. It gives us some idea of how you're thinking, helps us interpret any problems you report having, and also shows that you have put some effort into the problem on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not that hard. Just write something like that in action you want:

```
if (button1.ForeColor != Color.Green)
 {
   button1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
 }
 else
  {
   button1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
  }
```